# Searching Outlook calendar for appointments through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I’d like to search for free appointment spaces in my outlook calendar and save the closest 2 x 1 hour slots that land on different days. It’s working apart from I'm struggling to get a result on the current day - if I'm busy all day until AFTER the current time, but there is still space left for the remainder of the day, then it returns an answer.

When there were free appointments earlier in the day, prior to the current time, (and also free appointments later than the current time) then it doesn't like it and will just return 'no appointments found' (for the current day only)

I've put in a debug but it seems to 'give up' at about 11.30am before I presume Typename(olappt) equals nothing so moves on... Can anyone help me figure this out please?

Relevant bit:

```
                    With OLAppts
         ' capture start time and duration of each item
        Set OLAppt = .GetFirst

        Do While TypeName(OLAppt) <> "Nothing"
             ' find first free timeslot
            Select Case DateValue(dtmAppt)
            Case DateValue(Format(OLAppt.Start, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
            Debug.Print DateValue(Format(OLAppt.Start, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
            Debug.Print Format(OLAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn")
                
                    If Format(dtmNext, "Hh:Nn") < Format(OLAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn") Then

                         ' find gap before next appointment starts
                        If Format(OLAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn") < Format(dtmLastAppt, "Hh:Nn") Then
                            intDuration = DateDiff("n", dtmNext, Format(OLAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn"))
                        Else
                            intDuration = DateDiff("n", dtmNext, Format(dtmLastAppt, "Hh:Nn"))
                        End If

                         ' can we fit an appointment into the gap?
                        If intDuration >= intDefaultAppt Then
                    strList = strList & Format(dtmNext, "Hh:Nn ampm") & ";" & Format(DateAdd("n", intDuration, dtmNext), "Hh:Nn ampm") & ";"
                    End If


            End If

             ' find first available time after appointment
            dtmNext = DateAdd("n", OLAppt.Duration + intDuration, _
            dtmNext)

             ' don't go beyond last possible appointment time
            If dtmNext > dtmLastAppt Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End Select

        intDuration = 0

        Set OLAppt = .GetNext
        If dtmNext > dtmLastAppt Then
        Exit Do
    End If
'Debug.Print OLAppt = .Count

    Loop
End With
```

All the code of this element in case it's needed:

````
Option Explicit

Function FindFreeTime(dtmAppt As Date, dtmFirstAppt As Date, dtmLastAppt As Date, intDefaultAppt As Integer, i As Integer) As String
     '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     ' Purpose:      Capture all available timeslots (between appointments) on
     '               nominated day
     '
     ' Inputs:       dtmAppt         Date to search
     '
     ' Assumptions:  * Free timeslot must be >= default appointment time
     '               * Free timeslot must be between default start and end times for
     '                 appointments
     '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Dim objOL As New Outlook.Application ' Outlook
    Dim objNS As Namespace ' Namespace
    Dim OLFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder ' Calendar folder
    Dim OLAppt As Object ' Single appointment
    Dim OLAppts As Outlook.Items ' Appointment collection
    Dim strDay As String ' Day for appointment
    Dim strList As String ' List of all available timeslots
    Dim dtmNext As Date ' Next available time
    Dim intDuration As Integer ' Duration of free timeslot

    Const C_Procedure = "FindFreeTime" ' Procedure name


    dtmNext = dtmFirstAppt

    If i = 0 And dtmFirstAppt < Now Then
        dtmNext = TimeValue(Date + TimeSerial(Hour(Time) + 1, 0, 0))
    End If


    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

     ' list box column headings
 '   strList = "Start Time;End Time;"

     ' get full span of selected day
    strDay = "[Start] >= '" & dtmAppt & "' and " & "[Start] < '" & dtmAppt & " 11:59 pm'"

    Set objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Get the local calendar folder
    Set OLFldr = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    ' Get the appointments for the selected day
    Set OLAppts = OLFldr.Items.Restrict(strDay)

  '  dtmNext = C_dtmFirstAppt

     ' Sort the collection (required by IncludeRecurrences)
    OLAppts.Sort "[Start]"

     ' Make sure recurring appointments are included
    OLAppts.IncludeRecurrences = True

    With OLAppts
         ' capture start time and duration of each item
        Set OLAppt = .GetFirst

        Do While TypeName(OLAppt) <> "Nothing"
             ' find first free timeslot
            Select Case DateValue(dtmAppt)
            Case DateValue(Format(OLAppt.Start, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
            Debug.Print Format(OLAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn")
                
                    If Format(dtmNext, "Hh:Nn") < Format(OLAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn") Then

                         ' find gap before next appointment starts
                        If Format(OLAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn") < Format(dtmLastAppt, "Hh:Nn") Then
                            intDuration = DateDiff("n", dtmNext, Format(OLAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn"))
                        Else
                            intDuration = DateDiff("n", dtmNext, Format(dtmLastAppt, "Hh:Nn"))
                        End If

                         ' can we fit an appointment into the gap?
                        If intDuration >= intDefaultAppt Then
                    strList = strList & Format(dtmNext, "Hh:Nn ampm") & ";" & Format(DateAdd("n", intDuration, dtmNext), "Hh:Nn ampm") & ";"
                    End If


            End If

             ' find first available time after appointment
            dtmNext = DateAdd("n", OLAppt.Duration + intDuration, _
            dtmNext)

             ' don't go beyond last possible appointment time
            If dtmNext > dtmLastAppt Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End Select

        intDuration = 0

        Set OLAppt = .GetNext
        If dtmNext > dtmLastAppt Then
        Exit Do
    End If
'Debug.Print OLAppt = .Count

    Loop
End With

 ' capture remainder of day
intDuration = DateDiff("n", dtmNext, Format(dtmLastAppt, "Hh:Nn"))

If intDuration >= intDefaultAppt Then
    strList = strList & Format(dtmNext, "Hh:Nn ampm") & _
    ";" & Format(DateAdd("n", intDuration, dtmNext), "Hh:Nn ampm") & _
    ";"
End If

FindFreeTime = strList

ExitHere:
'On Error Resume Next
Set OLAppt = Nothing
Set OLAppts = Nothing
Set objNS = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
Exit Function

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & C_Procedure & vbCrLf & Err.Description
Resume ExitHere
End Function

Sub ScheduleAppointments()
    Dim dtmFirstAppt As Date
    Dim dtmLastAppt As Date
    Dim intDefaultAppt As Integer

    ' Set the default values for appointment times and duration
    dtmFirstAppt = #9:00:00 AM#
    dtmLastAppt = #8:00:00 PM#
    intDefaultAppt = 60 ' in minutes

    ' Call the function to find and schedule appointments
    ScheduleFreeTimeAppointments dtmFirstAppt, dtmLastAppt, intDefaultAppt
End Sub

Function ScheduleOutlookAppointment(dtmStart As Date, dtmEnd As Date) As Boolean
    ' Create a new appointment in the default calendar folder
    On Error Resume Next 'to handle error if Outlook is not open
    Dim objOL As New Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Namespace
    Dim objAppt As AppointmentItem

    Set objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objAppt = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    With objAppt
        .Subject = "Scheduled appointment"
        .Start = dtmStart
        .End = dtmEnd
        .Save
    End With

    ScheduleOutlookAppointment = (Err.Number = 0) ' return True if no error occurred, False otherwise
    Err.Clear
End Function

Sub ScheduleFreeTimeAppointments(ByVal dtmFirstAppt As Date, ByVal dtmLastAppt As Date, ByVal intDefaultAppt As Integer)
    Dim strList     As String
    Dim dtmAppt     As Date
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim found       As Integer
    Dim intCount    As Integer
    Dim dtmLastScheduled As Date

    ' Check if the first day should be skipped
    dtmAppt = Date
    If TimeValue(Now) > dtmLastAppt Then
        dtmAppt = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)
    End If

    For i = 0 To 13
        If i = 0 Then        ' First day
        If DateValue(Now) = dtmAppt And TimeValue(Now) > dtmFirstAppt Then
            ' Current time is after dtmFirstAppt, so set dtmFirstAppt to the next whole hour
            dtmFirstAppt = TimeValue(Date + TimeSerial(Hour(Time) + 1, 0, 0))

            Dim durDefaultAppt As Double
            Dim timeDefaultAppt As Date

            timeDefaultAppt = TimeValue(dtmFirstAppt)        ' Convert it into the time of day only.

            'Calculate the end of the appoint
            Dim timeEndAppt As Date
            timeEndAppt = DateAdd("n", intDefaultAppt, timeDefaultAppt)

            'Check if the end of the appointment is equal to or greater than the time of logging off.
            If timeEndAppt >= dtmLastAppt Then
                'if so then move on to the next day.
                i = 1
                'otherwise carry on
            End If
        End If
    Else        ' All other days
        dtmFirstAppt = #9:00:00 AM#
    End If
    If i > 0 Then


    dtmAppt = DateAdd("d", 1, dtmAppt)

    End If

    If Weekday(dtmAppt) >= 2 And Weekday(dtmAppt) <= 6 Then        ' Check if the date is a weekday
    strList = FindFreeTime(dtmAppt, dtmFirstAppt, dtmLastAppt, intDefaultAppt, i)
    If Len(strList) > 0 Then        ' A free timeslot was found
    Debug.Print "Free timeslots found For " & Format(dtmAppt, "dd/mm/yyyy") & ":"
    Debug.Print strList

    Dim arrSlots()  As String
    Dim j           As Integer
    Dim dtmStart    As Date
    Dim dtmEnd      As Date

    ' Schedule appointments for the free slots
    arrSlots = Split(strList, ";")
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrSlots) - 1 Step 2
        dtmStart = CDate(dtmAppt & " " & arrSlots(j))
        dtmEnd = CDate(dtmAppt & " " & arrSlots(j + 1))

        ' Check if the appointment is within the next two weeks
        
        If dtmStart >= Now() And dtmStart <= DateAdd("d", 14, Now()) Then
            If dtmStart >= DateAdd("d", 1, dtmLastScheduled) Then        ' Schedule appointment only if it's on a different day than the last scheduled appointment
            If ScheduleOutlookAppointment(dtmStart, DateAdd("n", intDefaultAppt, dtmStart)) Then        ' Set the appointment duration to intDefaultAppt
            intCount = intCount + 1
            dtmLastScheduled = dtmStart        ' Update the date of the last scheduled appointment

            ' Stop scheduling appointments once we've scheduled two
            If intCount = 2 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Error scheduling appointment For " & dtmStart
        End If
    End If
End If
Next j

found = found + 1
Else
    Debug.Print "No free timeslots found For " & Format(dtmAppt, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End If
Else
    Debug.Print "Skipping weekend day " & Format(dtmAppt, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End If

' Exit the loop if we've scheduled two appointments
If intCount = 2 Then
    Exit For
End If
Next i

' Notify the user if no appointments were scheduled
If intCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No available time slots found within the Next two weeks.", vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox intCount & " appointment(s) scheduled.", vbInformation
End If
End Sub
``` GB
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I gave below was wrong!

There was quite a bit wrong with the code but in the main my filter was wrong for the first day.
If i = 0 (i.e. if I'm on the current day), the filter now starts searching from after the current time of day. If i isn't 0 then the whole day is open to look at (the procedure will determine if it fits inside of the times I'm willing to offer).

The relevant bit for that is here:

```
dtmNext = dtmFirstAppt

    If i = 0 And dtmFirstAppt < Now Then
        dtmNext = TimeValue(Date + TimeSerial(Hour(Time) + 1, 0, 0))
    End If

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

If i = 0 Then
    ' Get the current time of day
    Dim currentTime As Date
    currentTime = Now()

    ' Use the current time of day as the start time for the search
    strDay = "[Start] >= '" & Format(dtmAppt, "Short Date") & " " & Format(dtmNext, "hh:nn") & "' And ([End] <= '" & dtmAppt & " 11:59 pm' Or [AllDayEvent] = True)"

Else
    ' Use the default start and end times for the search
    strDay = "[Start] >= '" & dtmAppt & "' And ([End] <= '" & dtmAppt & " 11:59 pm' Or [AllDayEvent] = True)"
End If
```

No changes to where I first thought the issue was.

I've had to also set (in the code) a temporary appointment in my diary with an hours appointment from the next whole hour - as if you don't have any remaining appointments in your diary, for the current day, then the code will dismiss today as an option (because it will fail the if statement in the procedure - below

```
If dtmStart >= Now() And DateDiff("n", Now(), dtmStart) >= 60 And dtmStart <= DateAdd("d", 14, Now()) Then
```

It still fails this because I think the filter will state from which point of time I am free from. If the last time I was free was in the past, then the if statement will fail. This filter:

```
strDay = "[Start] >= '" & Format(dtmAppt, "Short Date") & " " & Format(dtmNext, "hh:nn") & "' And ([End] <= '" & dtmAppt & " 11:59 pm' Or [AllDayEvent] = True)"
```

won’t return “free appointments” later in the day. Rather than forcing it to book in a time and assume I’m free (+ I’ve spent too long on this already!), I decided to push in a temporary appointment so that I will always have at least one appointment for the code to state that I’m free later in the day.
In addition, the ‘AllDayEvent’ filter is now working. For some reason I was having difficulty making this work; however the correct way of writing it is …
‘’’
…[AllDayEvent] = True)"
‘’’

Anyway, I've also included loading an email to the client offering a meeting (with some extra code to help with customise the email a little quicker).
The full code for this element in case someone wants to use it in the future is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Dim arrAppointments(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant

Function FindFreeTime(dtmAppt As Date, dtmFirstAppt As Date, dtmLastAppt As Date, intDefaultAppt As Integer, i As Integer) As String

    Dim objOL As New Outlook.Application ' Outlook
    Dim objNS As Namespace ' Namespace
    Dim OLFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder ' Calendar folder
    Dim olAppt As Object ' Single appointment
    Dim OLAppts As Outlook.Items ' Appointment collection
    Dim strDay As String ' Day for appointment
    Dim strList As String ' List of all available timeslots
    Dim dtmNext As Date ' Next available time
    Dim intDuration As Integer ' Duration of free timeslot

    Const C_Procedure = "FindFreeTime" ' Procedure name


    dtmNext = dtmFirstAppt

    If i = 0 And dtmFirstAppt < Now Then
        dtmNext = TimeValue(Date + TimeSerial(Hour(Time) + 1, 0, 0))
    End If

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

If i = 0 Then
    ' Get the current time of day
    Dim currentTime As Date
    currentTime = Now()

    ' Use the current time of day as the start time for the search
    strDay = "[Start] >= '" & Format(dtmAppt, "Short Date") & " " & Format(dtmNext, "hh:nn") & "' And ([End] <= '" & dtmAppt & " 11:59 pm' Or [AllDayEvent] = True)"

Else
    ' Use the default start and end times for the search
    strDay = "[Start] >= '" & dtmAppt & "' And ([End] <= '" & dtmAppt & " 11:59 pm' Or [AllDayEvent] = True)"
End If


    Set objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Get the local calendar folder
    Set OLFldr = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    ' Get the appointments for the selected day
    Set OLAppts = OLFldr.Items.Restrict(strDay)
     ' Sort the collection (required by IncludeRecurrences)
    OLAppts.Sort "[Start]"
     ' Make sure recurring appointments are included
    OLAppts.IncludeRecurrences = True

    With OLAppts
         ' capture start time and duration of each item
        Set olAppt = .GetFirst
        Do While TypeName(olAppt) <> "Nothing"
             ' find first free timeslot
            Select Case DateValue(dtmAppt)
            Case DateValue(Format(olAppt.Start, "dd/mm/yyyy"))
          '  Debug.Print Format(olAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn")

                    If Format(dtmNext, "Hh:Nn") < Format(olAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn") Then

                         ' find gap before next appointment starts
                        If Format(olAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn") < Format(dtmLastAppt, "Hh:Nn") Then
                            intDuration = DateDiff("n", dtmNext, Format(olAppt.Start, "Hh:Nn"))
                        Else
                            intDuration = DateDiff("n", dtmNext, Format(dtmLastAppt, "Hh:Nn"))
                        End If

                         ' can we fit an appointment into the gap?
                        If intDuration >= intDefaultAppt Then
                    strList = strList & Format(dtmNext, "Hh:Nn ampm") & ";" & Format(DateAdd("n", intDuration, dtmNext), "Hh:Nn ampm") & ";"
                    End If
            End If
             ' find first available time after appointment
            dtmNext = DateAdd("n", olAppt.Duration + intDuration, _
            dtmNext)

             ' don't go beyond last possible appointment time
            If dtmNext > dtmLastAppt Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        End Select

        intDuration = 0

        Set olAppt = .GetNext
        If dtmNext > dtmLastAppt Then
        Exit Do
    End If

    Loop
End With

 ' capture remainder of day
intDuration = DateDiff("n", dtmNext, Format(dtmLastAppt, "Hh:Nn"))

If intDuration >= intDefaultAppt Then
    strList = strList & Format(dtmNext, "Hh:Nn ampm") & _
    ";" & Format(DateAdd("n", intDuration, dtmNext), "Hh:Nn ampm") & _
    ";"
End If

FindFreeTime = strList

ExitHere:
Set olAppt = Nothing
Set OLAppts = Nothing
Set objNS = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
Exit Function

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & C_Procedure & vbCrLf & Err.Description
Resume ExitHere
End Function

Sub ScheduleAppointments()
    Dim dtmFirstAppt As Date
    Dim dtmLastAppt As Date
    Dim intDefaultAppt As Integer

    ' Set the default values for appointment times and duration
    dtmFirstAppt = #8:00:00 AM#
    dtmLastAppt = #7:00:00 PM#
    intDefaultAppt = 30 ' in minutes

    ' Call the function to find and schedule appointments
    ScheduleFreeTimeAppointments dtmFirstAppt, dtmLastAppt, intDefaultAppt
End Sub

Function ScheduleOutlookAppointment(dtmStart As Date, dtmEnd As Date) As Boolean
    ' Create a new appointment in the default calendar folder
    On Error Resume Next 'to handle error if Outlook is not open
    Dim objOL As New Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Namespace
    Dim objAppt As AppointmentItem

    Set objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objAppt = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)

    With objAppt
        .Subject = "Scheduled appointment"
        .Start = dtmStart
        .End = dtmEnd
        .Save
    End With

    ScheduleOutlookAppointment = (Err.Number = 0) ' return True if no error occurred, False otherwise
    Err.Clear
End Function

Sub SendInitialEmail(ByVal clientName As String, ByVal colleagueName As String, ByVal manualDate As Date, ByVal appointmentDate1 As String, ByVal appointmentTime1 As Date, ByVal appointmentDate2 As String, ByVal appointmentTime2 As Date)
' Create a new Outlook email message
Dim objOL As New Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set objMail = objOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With objMail
    .Subject = "Initial Summary and Next Steps"
    .To = "<client email address>"
    .HTMLBody = "Hello " & clientName & ",<br><br>" _
              & "email contents..."

   If Not appointmentDate1 = "" Then   ' check if appointmentDate1 is not empty
    Dim appointment1Date As Date   ' declare a variable to store the date portion of appointmentDate1
    appointment1Date = DateValue(Left(appointmentDate1, 10))   ' extract the first 10 characters from appointmentDate1 and convert to a Date type

    Dim appointment1Description As String   ' declare a variable to store the description of the appointment time slot
    If appointment1Date = Date Then    ' check if appointment1Date is today's date
        appointment1Description = "today"   ' set the description to "today"
           
            ElseIf appointment1Date = Date + 1 Then   ' check if appointment1Date is tomorrow's date
            appointment1Description = "tomorrow, " & Format(appointment1Date, "dddd dd mmmm")   ' set the description to "tomorrow" followed by the formatted date
            
            Else
            appointment1Description = Format(appointment1Date, "dddd dd mmmm")   ' set the description to the formatted date
        End If

    Dim appointment2Description As String   ' declare a variable to store the description of the second appointment time slot
    If Not appointmentDate2 = "" Then   ' check if appointmentDate2 is not equal to the default date value
        Dim appointment2Date As Date   ' declare a variable to store the date portion of appointmentDate1
        appointment2Date = DateValue(Left(appointmentDate2, 10))   ' extract the first 10 characters from appointmentDate1 and convert to a Date type

        If appointment2Date = Date + 1 Then   ' check if appointmentDate2 is tomorrow's date
            appointment2Description = "tomorrow, " & Format(appointmentDate2, "dddd dd mmmm")   ' set the description to "tomorrow" followed by the formatted date
        Else
            appointment2Description = Format(appointmentDate2, "dddd dd mmmm")   ' set the description to the formatted date
        End If

        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "I'm currently free for a chat on " & appointment1Description & ", at " & Format(appointmentTime1, "h:mm AMPM") & ", or " & appointment2Description & ", at " & Format(appointmentTime2, "h:mm AMPM") & ". Do any of these times work with you?<br><br>"
        ' add the appointment slots to the email body, formatted with the time in 12-hour clock format with AM/PM indicator
    Else
        .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "I'm currently free for a chat " & appointment1Description & " at " & Format(CDate(appointmentDate1), "h:mm AMPM") & ". Does this work with you?<br><br>"
        ' add the first appointment slot to the email body, formatted with the time in 12-hour clock format with AM/PM indicator, and the second appointment slot set to a specific date and time
    End If
Else
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "Unfortunately, I couldn't find any available time slots within the next two weeks. <br><br>"
End If

.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "Kind regards, <br><br>" _
          & "Ed"

.Display
' finish formatting the email body, adding the signature, and display the email in Outlook for the user to send.
End With


Set objMail = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ScheduleFreeTimeAppointments(ByVal dtmFirstAppt As Date, ByVal dtmLastAppt As Date, ByVal intDefaultAppt As Integer)
    Dim strList     As String
    Dim dtmAppt     As Date
    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim found       As Integer
    Dim intCount    As Integer
    Dim dtmLastScheduled As Date

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    
    ' Create a temporary appointment starting from the next whole hour
    Dim dtmStart As Date
    Dim dtmEnd As Date
    dtmStart = Date + TimeSerial(Hour(Now), Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Minute(Now), 60), 0)
    dtmEnd = DateAdd("n", 60, dtmStart)
    Dim olApt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Set olApt = olApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    olApt.Start = dtmStart
    olApt.End = dtmEnd
    olApt.Subject = "Temporary Appointment"
    olApt.Save
    
    
    ' Check if the first day should be skipped
    dtmAppt = Date
    If TimeValue(Now) > dtmLastAppt Then
        dtmAppt = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)
    End If

    For i = 0 To 13
        If i = 0 Then        ' First day
       ' If DateValue(Now) = dtmAppt And TimeValue(Now) > dtmFirstAppt Then
        If DateValue(Now) = dtmAppt And TimeValue(Now) > dtmLastAppt Then
            ' Current time is after dtmFirstAppt, so set dtmFirstAppt to the next whole hour
            dtmFirstAppt = TimeValue(Date + TimeSerial(Hour(Time) + 1, 0, 0))

            Dim durDefaultAppt As Double
            Dim timeDefaultAppt As Date

            timeDefaultAppt = TimeValue(dtmFirstAppt)        ' Convert it into the time of day only.

            'Calculate the end of the appoint
            Dim timeEndAppt As Date
            timeEndAppt = DateAdd("n", intDefaultAppt, timeDefaultAppt)

            'Check if the end of the appointment is equal to or greater than the time of logging off.
            If timeEndAppt >= dtmLastAppt Then
                'if so then move on to the next day.
                i = 1
                'otherwise carry on
            End If
        End If
    Else        ' All other days
        dtmFirstAppt = #8:00:00 AM#
    End If
    If i > 0 Then

    dtmAppt = DateAdd("d", 1, dtmAppt)

    End If

    If Weekday(dtmAppt) >= 2 And Weekday(dtmAppt) <= 6 Then        ' Check if the date is a weekday
    strList = FindFreeTime(dtmAppt, dtmFirstAppt, dtmLastAppt, intDefaultAppt, i)
    If Len(strList) > 0 Then        ' A free timeslot was found
    Dim arrSlots()  As String
    Dim j           As Integer


    ' Schedule appointments for the free slots
    arrSlots = Split(strList, ";")
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrSlots) - 1 Step 2
        dtmStart = CDate(dtmAppt & " " & arrSlots(j))
        dtmEnd = CDate(dtmAppt & " " & arrSlots(j + 1))

        ' Check if the appointment is within the next two weeks

      '  If dtmStart >= Now() And dtmStart <= DateAdd("d", 14, Now()) Then
        If dtmStart >= Now() And DateDiff("n", Now(), dtmStart) >= 60 And dtmStart <= DateAdd("d", 14, Now()) Then

            If DateValue(dtmStart) >= DateAdd("d", 1, DateValue(dtmLastScheduled)) Then
          '  If dtmStart >= DateAdd("d", 1, dtmLastScheduled) Then        ' Schedule appointment only if it's on a different day than the last scheduled appointment
                If ScheduleOutlookAppointment(dtmStart, DateAdd("n", intDefaultAppt, dtmStart)) Then        ' Set the appointment duration to intDefaultAppt
                    intCount = intCount + 1

                    arrAppointments(intCount, 1) = dtmStart ' Store the date of the appointment
                    Debug.Print dtmStart
                    Debug.Print arrAppointments(1, 1)
                    Debug.Print arrAppointments(2, 1)
                    
                    arrAppointments(intCount, 2) = intDefaultAppt ' Store the duration of the appointment
                    dtmLastScheduled = dtmStart        ' Update the date of the last scheduled appointment
                    
                    ' Stop scheduling appointments once we've scheduled two
                    If intCount = 2 Then

                        Exit For
                    End If
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Error scheduling appointment For " & dtmStart
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j

found = found + 1
Else
   ' Debug.Print "No free timeslots found For " & Format(dtmAppt, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End If
Else
   ' Debug.Print "Skipping weekend day " & Format(dtmAppt, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End If

' Exit the loop if we've scheduled two appointments
If intCount = 2 Then
    Exit For
End If
Next i

If intCount = 0 Then
    SendInitialEmail "John", "Sarah", DateSerial(2023, 3, 6), #1/1/4501#, "", #1/1/4501#, ""
ElseIf intCount = 1 Then
    SendInitialEmail "John", "Sarah", DateSerial(2023, 3, 6), arrAppointments(1, 1), Format(arrAppointments(1, 1), "h:mm AM/PM"), #1/1/4501#, ""
ElseIf intCount = 2 Then
    SendInitialEmail "John", "Sarah", DateSerial(2023, 3, 6), arrAppointments(1, 1), Format(arrAppointments(1, 1), "h:mm AM/PM"), arrAppointments(2, 1), Format(arrAppointments(2, 1), "h:mm AM/PM")
End If

If intCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "No available time slots found within the next two weeks.", vbInformation
Else
'MsgBox intCount & " appointment(s) scheduled.", vbInformation
End If

    olApt.Delete
    Set olApt = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

<s>Actually I think I've fixed it. Quite simple in the end -
I've modified the condition to check if the current time is later than the dtmLastAppt instead of dtmFirstAppt. This ensures that the code skips the current day only if all appointment slots for the day have already passed.
Changed from:</s>

```
 If DateValue(Now) = dtmAppt And TimeValue(Now) > dtmFirstAppt Then
```

To:

```
If DateValue(Now) = dtmAppt And TimeValue(Now) > dtmLastAppt Then
```

I'm keeping this post up as there is very little documentation online of how to find free appointments in your Outlook calendar using the restrict method.